# Codeigniter pagination does not display data

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeigniter pagination and it displays based on a passingID, the first page shows link only but no data

My controller:

```
public function searchpagenat($hsp)

$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "User/searchpagenat/";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->Doctor_model->get_doc_by_hospital($hsp);
$config['per_page'] = 4;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$segment = $this->uri->segment (3);
$data['serv'] = $this->Doctor_model->get_doc_by_hsp($config['per_page'], $segment,$hsp);
```

and model

```
public function get_doc_by_hospital($hsp)  
{ 
$this->db->select('*');  
$this->db->from('tbl_doctor');
$this->db->where('hosp_id',$hsp);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
}
public function get_doc_by_hsp($limit, $offset, $hsp)
{
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('tbl_doctor'); 
$this->db->where('hosp_id',$hsp);
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query= $this->db->get();  
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
return $query;
}
```

here the query are working the issue is the passing id the pagination link working on the bases of passing id the passing id is grater than count show no data.

how its solve?any way?please help me?

Comment: have you loaded pagination library?

Comment: have you added this? { $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();  }

Comment: In get_doc_by_hsp($limit, $offset, $hsp) use { return $query->result(); }

Comment: @DanishAli yes i will load it will workin probelm is passing id grater than count no data show

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571329/6537233

Comment: @AbdulSalam that code and my code are running same issue

Comment: Maybe you need a little more understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862752/how-to-use-pagination-in-codeigniter-with-this-db-query/48871100#48871100

Comment: @BrianGottier thanks its help full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the pagination code like

```
$config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```