# How to show specific pagination link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i am doing pagiation with codeigniter, its showing all the pagination link like
[image]

But i just want to show something like 1 2 3 Next.
 My code is

```
    $start_index = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $total_reports = $data['losts'];
  $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Lost/list';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($data['losts']);
    $config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
  $config['num_links'] =  count($data['losts']);
        // Open tag for CURRENT link.
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';

    // Close tag for CURRENT link.
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

    // By clicking on performing NEXT pagination.
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';

    // By clicking on performing PREVIOUS pagination.
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571329/6537233

Comment: Take a look at : [Customizing the Pagination](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `$config['num_links']` with total numbers of rows.

But you need to set it to number of links to be generated.

```
$config['num_links'] = 3;
```

> The number of “digit” links you would like before and after the
>   selected page number. For example, the number 2 will place two digits
>   on either side, as in the example links at the very top of this page.

Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

Comment: right, but if i click next it continuously increase the link like after clicking next it will show 1 2 3 4